# \frame with options

Tags: beamer

If I want to use a "fragile" frame in a presentation I have to write

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{FRAME TITLE}


\end{frame}
```

Is there a way using the

```
\frame{
  \frametitle{FRAME TITLE}
}
```

syntax?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use the environment form?

Comment: I wrote all frame using the second way filling with the title and some keywords. Now I'm filling the frames with content and have to include in same frames listings. So the frames need to be fragile. Therefor I have to rewrite those frames. Using the second way would be easier. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no, or at least not using the documented interfaces. This can be verified with an example such as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame[fragile]{% Fails
  \frametitle{FRAME TITLE}
} 
\end{document}
```

However, using some code which is there *purely* for compatibility you may be OK:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame[containsverbatim]{
  \frametitle{FRAME TITLE}
  \begin{verbatim}
    Hello % # &
  \end{verbatim}
} 
\end{document}
```

Reading over the code, it's clear that the `\frame` approach for collecting frames is there mainly for historical reasons. The environment-based approach has more flexibility, particularly as without 'trickery' collecting verbatim material inside an argument is much more awkward/risky than within an environment.

Whilst the current maintenance team are committed to avoiding breaking `beamer` or altering 'defined' behaviours, that does not mean all of them are equally sensible! Speaking personally, I would not recommend using `\frame...` for new `beamer` slides at all.

Comment: Note: `containsverbatim` is not documented but will remain in the code base as it's there to avoid breaking old presentations.