# Is there a difference between \frame{stuff} and \begin{frame} stuff \end{frame}

Tags: beamer

I'm a bit of a beginner to beamer and have been using

```
\frame{
stuff
}
```

until now.  Today I received a tex file to merge into my lecture material and see the use of

```
\begin{frame}
 stuff
\end{frame}
```

I was just wondering if there is a difference between the two and whether I should be using the latter? Does it allow more functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quote from the beamer user guide:

> The command `\frame` is supported for legacy documents.

If you are writing new code, you should use

```
\begin{frame}
 stuff
\end{frame}
```

otherwise you might sooner or later run into problems, for example [\frame with options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153982/36296)